# Losing the data while iterating the table by Rows with Java & JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

In the jsp page, depending on the number of records, this tr will be executed and displayed to the users.

```
for(int i=0; i<NoOfRecords.length;i++){
<tr>
    <td width="15%"> Transit Account & <%= acctId%>
    </td>
    <td width="15%"> <%=MultiModeConstants.GL_ACCT_NO%>
    </td>
    <td width="45%">
    <input type="text" id="multiModeAcctNo" name="multiModeAcctNo" desc="Multi Mode Transit Account Number" maxlength="9" class="body" size="9" tabindex="3" >
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
        Deposit
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
        $ <%= transactioAmount%>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Based on the number of records, Number of rows would be populated in the jsp page,
**multiModeAcctNo**, field will be entered by User(**multiModeAcctNo**);

For example if there are 4 records, there are 4 times I enter different **multiModeAcctNo** in the page.

After submitting the page, I am able to get only the first field, I am losing the other 3 values.

Suppose if I only read One Row, then I am able to get the data fine. What do I need to do?

I am using java & jsp as the programming languages.

Comment: Although you are iterating upto total length, you are not getting the index for each value of the object. And how did you store the value in your object? Check some example first on how to iterate through content of an object http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/the-enhanced-for-loop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create dynamic names for input fields may be as:

```
for(int i=0; i<NoOfRecords.length;i++){
<tr>
    <td width="15%"> Transit Account & <%= acctId%>
    </td>
    <td width="15%"> <%=MultiModeConstants.GL_ACCT_NO%>
    </td>
    <td width="45%">
    <input type="text" id="multiModeAcctNo_<%=i%>" name="multiModeAcctNo_<%=i%>" desc="Multi Mode Transit Account Number" maxlength="9" class="body" size="9" tabindex="3" >
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
        Deposit
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
        $ <%= transactioAmount%>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Now in your servlet [hoping that you also get NoOfRecords.length there] get value of each input by providing it's dynamically generated names. May be as:

```
String str = new String[NoOfRecords.length];
for(int i=0; i<NoOfRecords.length;i++){
    str[i] = request.getParameter("multiModeAcctNo_"+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of submission you're doing but you may want to use a different ID for your input field, as you iterate you are using the same `multiModeAcctNo` ID in your `<input>`.

If you're using a form and POSTing the element you may want to name your `input` to something like `multiModeAcctNo[]` then in your JSP file refer it as a POST array element (not sure if that's possible with Java). Just an idea.